# My mac is sluggish and something is taking up a lot of my CPU

Tags: performance

Any idea what `quicklookd` is? It seems to be using up a lot of my CPU resources.

I'm running MacOS Sierra 10.12.1 on a Macbook Air.

[image: Activity Monitor]

Comment: quicklookd is a daemon which manages [Quick Look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Look). The apparently high CPU use is a faulty presentation due to some memory overflow. You can safely choose the process in Activity Monitor and quit or force-quit (kill) it by hitting the ⓧ button.

Answer (score 1):

That is basically finders previewing system. Try restarting finder.